# Completeness and closedness

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I got confused with these two concepts when consider the set $\Omega$ of real valued continuous functions defined on $[0, 1]$. By definition, $\Omega$ is certainly closed since every set is a closed subset of itself. However, $\Omega$ is not complete. One counter example is the function sequence $(f_n) = x^{n}$. Pointwisely $(f_n)$ converges to the function $f = I_{\{0<x\leq 1\}} + 0\times I_{\{x=0\}}$, which is not continuous.

Now reconsider the above example. By definition a set is closed if it contains all its limit points. However, $\Omega$ does not seem to satisfy this criterion. That is, $\Omega$ is not closed, which contradicts the previous statement. I am wondering where I understand wrongly. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you say that $\Omega$ is closed by definition?

Comment: Closedness is a property that subsets of a topological space have (or have not). As a subspace of which topological space is $\Omega$ closed? Completeness is a property that (subsets of) metric spaces, or more generally uniform spaces, can have. With respect to which metric or uniform structure shall the completeness of $\Omega$ be considered? It is complete when endowed with the metric arising from the supremum norm.

Comment: @qaphla Every set is a closed subset of itself. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that a closed set must contain all of its limit points. But one must be careful: the definition states that the limit points *must be in the space*. So in your example, the limit of the sequence $x^n$ is indeed not in the space, but that does not contradict the set being closed.

For an example of what I mean, consider the metric space $X=[0,1)$ with the standard Euclidean metric. The subset $[1/2,1)$ is closed as a subset of $X$; the point 1 is not in $X$, and hence does not count as a limit point of $[1/2,1)$ in $X$.

What this does show is that the space is not *universally* closed, which means that it isn't closed in any larger metric space. So if you add in the limit of that sequence to the space and make the space larger, then your $\Omega$ won't be closed as a subspace of that larger metric space.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. That is, closedness is a relative concept. Does this mean completeness is a universal concept, please? That is, all the limit points should be included in the space.

Comment: Yes. A characterization of completeness is that every Cauchy sequence in the space converges in the space. You can think of Cauchy sequences as "hole detectors," and if you find one which doesn't converge, it's intuitively telling you that there's a hole in your space, or that there is a missing limit point.